# Intellisense в Visual Studio 2012 для HTML-атрибутов

Tags: html, visual-studio-2012

Всем привет!

Есть ли в `Visual Studio 2012 Intellisense` (автодополнение) для HTML-атрибутов? Оно работает для HTML-тегов, хотя как раз для них меньше всего нужно :). А для HTML/CSS-атрибутов и их значений - неужели нет?

Comment: если Вы используете студию для верстки и Вам нужен IntelliSence, то это проблема. хотя это, конечно, оффтоп. я верстал в Notepad++ с подсветкой селекторов, и это было удобно.

Answer (score 1):

Установите [`WebEssentials`](http://vswebessentials.com/), всё что нужно для веба и VS